# How to use TELUGU_SCRIPT flag in Blackberry java

Tags: blackberry

what is the use of TELUGU_SCRIPT flag in blackberry java & how to use this

Comment: Some context would be useful.  Where do you see this flag?

Comment: in blackberry JDK.for example:Font f = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.TELUGU_SCRIPT, 20);